# How to insert recid using SSIS in dynamics table?

Tags: ssis, x++, dynamics-ax-2012, axapta

How to insert recId in dynamics Ax table SSIS?

Answer (score 5):

Do not do it.

But if you insists: http://daxguy.blogspot.dk/2010/03/dynamics-ax-2009-bulk-data-insert-using.html

Answer (score 3):

If you want to insert records directly into the SQL database using SSIS, you cannot on-the-fly get RecId's easily from SQL manipulation alone, so another option is reserving the recid's using x++ in an x++ job or service, for example:

```
static void ReserveRecs(Args _args)
{
    systemSequence seq;

    seq = new SystemSequence();
    if (seq)
    {
        // Suspend automatic recId allocation.
        Seq.suspendRecIds(tableName2id("TableName"));
        //Change the number below to reflect the amount of recid's you want reserved.
        info(int642str(seq.reserveValues(1, tableName2id("TableName"))));
        Seq.removeRecIdSuspension(tableName2id("TableName"));
    }
}
```

This job will take a table, and reserve one recId to be used that the system will simply ignore/skip. A word of caution, if you accidently reserve a huge number it's not easy to get those reservations back, and int64's do have a limit (albeit a huge number).

You could probably create a service in x++ that you could hit from your SSIS job where you tell a table name and an amount to reserve, and get an int64 back, that way you could automate the SSIS job.

Answer (score 0):

In this post is explained how to maintain the Number Sequence table to insert RecId, although this is a risky operation that has to be avoided always that it can be.

http://sumitsaxfactor.wordpress.com/2011/04/01/handling-recids-in-sql-server/